# Redmine Eclipse mylyn plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, redmine, mylyn

I want to connect eclipse with redmine via mylyn plugin developed especially for redmine. I have installed plugin and connector for redmine and for eclipse.

Installation was successful both for redmine and eclipse.

The problem is when I add new query in task list, I get Unexpected status code - 404!? My redmine instance is local. Here are the details regarding the plugin, connector and my eclipse version:

- Mylyn Connector: Redmine 0.3.7.201203072118  - ECLIPSE
- Mylyn Connector plugin 2.8.2 stable - REDMINE
- Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)

Now I know about howToMylyn on redmine site and that works as long as my projects are public and this is not useful for us because our projects are private. The generic web connector requires username and password but they are not used? So this is not the solution. And I browsed a lot.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

[eclipse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aECZF.png)

Comment: here is the redmine log file:

**Started GET "/redmine/mylyn/issuestatus?key=9c36b97298b5f13f8b370fdc91aa1106288cd021" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-25 20:20:40 +0100
Processing by MylynConnector::IssueStatusController#all as XML
  Parameters: {"key"=>"9c36b97298b5f13f8b370fdc91aa1106288cd021"}
  Current user: filip (id=1)
Completed 404 Not Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find IssueStatus with 'id'=all):
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'**

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. The plugin (github.com/danmunn/redmine_mylyn_connector) for redmine is not working correctly, at least for newer redmine and eclipse versions. This is the plugin that must be used for new versions: github.com/joaopedrotaveira/redmine_mylyn_connector

Comment: Hi @frapelo, if you encounter any CRSF issues with newer redmine versions, try to use Eclipse plugin from https://github.com/ljader/redmine-mylyn-plugin .